# In a recursive function, where to store results?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, boolean, return-value

I'm currently trying to let JavaScript generate a truth table for a boolean function. Given a function, the code should just list all boolean combinations possible, with the function output from each combination.

As for generating all combinations, I put this together (simplified to the combinations code only):

```
var table = [];
function combinations(current) {
    var current = current || [];
    if(current.length === 3) {
        table.push(current);
    } else {
        var c = copy(current);
        c.push(true);
        combinations(c);

        c = copy(current);
        c.push(false);
        combinations(c);
    }
}

function copy(a) {
    var r = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) r.push(a[i]);
    return r;
}

combinations(); // now table consists of each pair of 3 boolean values
```

So basically when it has reached a combination (i.e. `current.length === 3`), it pushes a result record to `table`. I was wondering, however, whether this is the recommended way of storing results of a recursive function.

I faced the recommendation of using `return` inside the recursive function, but how would one implement such a thing - i.e., if `combinations` in the end has to return an array containing all elements, how is it possible to do so? I could, of course, just use `return table` in the end, but I'm actually looking for a way to do this all inside the function, without an external variable like now.

So, how do I make `combinations` return the results as an array without using an external variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

```
function combinations(current) {
    var current = current || [];
    if(current.length === 3) {
        return [current];
    } else {
        return combinations(current.concat(true)).concat(combinations(current.concat(false)));
    }
}

var table = combinations(); // now table consists of each pair of 3 boolean values

console.log(table);
```

Much more elegant, no?

***[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/46E6M/)***

Answer (score 2):

To avoid polluting the global space you could use a closure to contain your recursive function. There is an excellent writeup of this concept at http://drewwells.net/blog/2010/recursion-in-javascript/.

Comment: There is no need to use this construct to encapsulate the result. See my answer.

Comment: I changed "would use" to "could use" to indicate that this is just one option.

Comment: @jsumners the link is dead

Comment: @Dropout I love it when people reorganize and don't create 302s.

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution seems fine to me. It might not be the most elegant, but it is simple and does the job (the only ugly bit is the hardcoded 3 - you should turn that into a parameter)

Your real question seems to be more language-agnostic than Javascript. If you want the function to return the combinations, than you can prefectly do so, just clearly have in mind what your function should return and write the base and recursive cases:

```
function combinations(domain, n){
    //returns a list of combinations of length `n` with elements from `domain`
    if(n <= 0){
        return [[]]; //the empty combination is the only solution
    }else{
        var small_combs = combinations(domain, n-1);
        var big_combs = [];
        for(var i=0; i<domain.length; i++){
            for(var j=0; j<small_combs.length; j++){
                big_combs.push(small_combs[j].concat(domain[i]))
            }
        }
        return big_combs;
     }
}

table = combinations([true, false], 3);
```

Comment: Thanks. Some feedback though - you check for `i` in the `j` loop. Also, in JavaScript `int` doesn't exist and `arr + arr` is not possible, but I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = { "object": "page", "entry": [{ "id": "1588811284674233", "time": 1511177084837, "messaging": [{ "sender": { "id": "1393377930761248" }, "recipient": { "id": "1588811284674233" }, "timestamp": 1511177084553, "message": { "mid": "mid.$cAAX_9pLcfu1mCnGmiVf2Sxd2erI2", "seq": 1882, "text": "a" } }] }] };
function getKey(obj, data) {
      var data = data || [];
      if (obj) {
        var keys = Object.keys(obj);
        for (var pos in keys) {
          console.log();
          data.push(keys[pos]);
          if ((obj[keys[pos]].constructor === Array)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < obj[keys[pos]].length; i++) {
              getKey(obj[keys[pos]][i], data);
            }
          }
          else if (obj[keys[pos]].constructor === Object) {
            getKey(obj[keys[pos]], data);
          }
        }
        return data;
      }
    }
```